# Windows Batch - Extract values for ffmpeg processing

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, cmd, file-search

I have dozens of json files, and I am trying to find two values in each of them and assign the results to two separate variables for ffmpeg processing.

An example json file looks like this:

```
{
    "year": "2018",
    "track": "12",
... other data omitted
}
```

I wish to extract 2018 and 12 so that I can use them in the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "same_file_name_as_json.m4a" -metadata:s:a:0 year=2018 --metadata:s:a:0 track=12 -acodec libmp3lame "same_file_name_as_json.mp3"
```

Is it possible to write a single batch file to achieve the desired result? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a complete novice at findstr and setting variables. Thank you.

EDITED:

```
set "year=" & set "track="
for %%i in (*.json) do (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%a in ("%%i") do (
    set "%%~a=%%~b"
    if defined year if defined track goto :CONT
    )
:CONT
C:\ffmpeg -i "%%~ni.m4a" -metadata:s:a:0 year=%year% -metadata:s:a:0 track=%track% -acodec libmp3lame "%%~ni.mp3"
)
pause
```

Comment: Better use a language that natively supports JSON rather than treating the data just as normal text with a batch script…

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Will it help if I save the json data as a text file? I intended to that actually.

Comment: Well, JSON *is* already text, but structured in a specific way which batch scripting does not know anything about. Of cuorse you can use `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ("file.json") do set "%%~M=%%~N"` to get variables `%year%` and `%track%`, but this relies on the formatting as you have shonw it; if there were more, less or moved line-breaks, this would fail…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows batch scripting does not understand the JSON file format, so it is better to use a language natively supports it. It is not the best idea to treat JSON as "normal" text, because only a slight change (for instance, added, deleted, or moved line-breaks) that do not violate the JSON format can still make big troubles then.

That said, given that the JSON file exactly appears as you have shown it and it features Unix- or DOS/Windows-style line-breaks (that is, a carriage-return character followed by a line-feed character), this code could work for you:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ("file.json") do set "%%~M=%%~N"
echo year  = %year%
echo track = %track%
```

If you have got a huge JSON file you do not want to unnecessarily fully process, you could use this code instead:

```cmd
set "year=" & set "track="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ("file.json") do (
    set "%%~M=%%~N"
    if defined year if defined track goto :CONT
)
:CONT
echo year  = %year%
echo track = %track%
```

If the (non-array) values you want to extract may also contain one of the defined delimiters (`{`, `:`, `}`, `,`, <kbd>SPACE</kbd>), you could extend the code to this, given that the values do not contain the characters `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`:

```cmd
set "year=" & set "track="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims={:}, " %%M in ("file.json") do (
    for %%K in (%%N) do set "%%~M=%%~K"
    if defined year if defined track goto :CONT
)
:CONT
echo year  = %year%
echo track = %track%
```

To prevent the script from assigning unwanted superfluous variables, you may try this:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ("file.json") do (
    if "%%~M"=="year" (set "%%~M=%%~N") else if "%%~M"=="track" set "%%~M=%%~N"
)
echo year  = %year%
echo track = %track%
```

Or this, which prepreocesses the data by the `findstr` command and filters out the desired lines:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ('
    findstr /R /C:"^ *\"year\" *:" /C:"^ *\"track\" *:" "file.json"
') do set "%%~M=%%~N"
echo year  = %year%
echo track = %track%
```

---

Based on your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64706904/3), let me suggest to use the last of the above methods, because there is no `goto :CONT`, which cannot be used within loops as it breaks the block context, and it does not assign additional unwanted variables. Since variables are written *and* read within the loop body, you have to enable and apply [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion). I would do all that the following way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Iterate over the `*.json` files in the current working directory (`%CD%`);
rem    to use the parent directory of this script, use `%~dp0*.json` instead: */
for %%I in ("*.json") do (
    rem // Store name of current JSON file in variable:
    set "name=%%~nI"
    rem // Clear variables for later check for availability:
    set "year=" & set "track="
    rem // Process the current JSON file:
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={:}, " %%M in ('
        findstr /R /C:"^ *\"year\" *:" /C:"^ *\"track\" *:" "%%~I"
    ') do (
        rem // Assign year and track variables:
        set "%%~M=%%~N"
        rem // Check of both year and track are available:
        if defined year if defined track (
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Eventually execute `ffmpeg` tool using all the derived data:
            ffmpeg -i "!name!.m4a" -metadata:s:a:0 year=!year! -metadata:s:a:0 track=!track! -acodec libmp3lame "!name!.mp3"
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: `... in ('findstr /i "year track" "file.json") do ...` can also reduce the lines to process if only a limited number of many values are required (and avoids creating variables that will never be used - or worse, overwrite already existing variables).

Comment: All the codes you and Stephan provided work beautifully. Thank you very much! I tried to add looping commands to one of these codes so that I could process multiple files, but it only processed one file in the directory, and it couldn't seem to read the corresponding m4a files (i.e., ffmpeg commad shows "%%~ni.m4a" instead of real file name). I think there must be something terribly wrong with my code. Would be very grateful if you could take a look at it in the edited area in the main post. Thank you.

Comment: Two problems: 1. `goto :CONT` cannot be used in a loop; 2. lack of delayed expansion. See my updated answer…

Comment: The updated method works like a charm. Thank you so much. There are many commands in the script that I have very limited or zero knowledge of. Without your help, I would not have been able to make this batch work.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have dozens of json files...*

Windows' `cmd` doesn't support JSON, so you'd have to resort to PowerShell, or use an external tool that does. You might find [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) interesting.

To extract the value for "year" and "track":

```
xidel -s input.json -e "$json/(year,track)"
#or
xidel -s input.json -e "$json/year,$json/track"
2018
12
```

To export to a variable `%year%` and `%track%`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s input.json -e "$json/(year:=year,track:=track)" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
#or
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s input.json -e "year:=$json/year,track:=$json/track" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```

---

You don't however need variables to create the strings (`ffmpeg` commands) you want. `xidel` can do that too.

You could use a `FOR`-loop to iterate over all your JSON-files...

```
FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @xidel -s %A -e "$json/concat('ffmpeg -i \"%~nA.m4a\" -metadata:s:a:0 year=',year,' --metadata:s:a:0 track=',track,' -acodec libmp3lame \"%~nA.mp3\"')"
ffmpeg -i "name-of-json-file.m4a" -metadata:s:a:0 year=2018 --metadata:s:a:0 track=12 -acodec libmp3lame "name-of-json-file.mp3"
```

...but to call `xidel` for each and every JSON-file is very inefficient. `xidel` can do this much more efficiently.
`xidel`'s equivalent for `FOR %A IN (*.json) DO @ECHO %A` is `xidel -se "file:list(.,false(),'*.json')"`

Then you can use the following query to process all your JSON-files at once:

```
xidel -se "for $x in file:list(.,false(),'*.json') return json-doc($x)/concat('ffmpeg -i \"',replace($x,'json','m4a'),'\" -metadata:s:a:0 year=',year,' --metadata:s:a:0 track=',track,' -acodec libmp3lame \"',replace($x,'json','mp3'),'\"')"
```

Prettified command/query:

```
xidel -se ^"^
  for $x in file:list(.,false(),'*.json') return^
  json-doc($x)/concat(^
    'ffmpeg -i \^"',^
    replace($x,'json','m4a'),^
    '\^" -metadata:s:a:0 year=',^
    year,^
    ' --metadata:s:a:0 track=',^
    track,^
    ' -acodec libmp3lame \^"',^
    replace($x,'json','mp3'),^
    '\^"'^
  )^
"
```